# redirecting DNS to new webhost

Tags: dns, redirection

I am changing web host for an existing site and before redirecting the nameservers to the new host I want to install a php shopping cart.  I have uploaded the shopping cart to my new web host but when I enter the admin page for the cart (www.example.com/admin.php )I get a 404 error because the page is being served from my old web host. I am using the host file on windows to redirect the dns to the new host's IP and the redirect works for the HTML pages but not for the shopping cart even though it is the same domain.  The host file redirect I am using is: ##.##.##.##  example.com.  Hopefully this makes sense.  Kind of new at this.

Comment: Adding your custom entry to %WinDir%\ System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts should be good enough for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things you can try:

1. Flush your DNS cache (assuming your using windows), type `ipconfig /flushdns`
2. Explicitly add www.example.com to your hosts file (instead of just example.com)

Comment: The www.example.com was the solution.  I didn't realize I needed both forms of the URL.  Thank you.